# No option of logging into ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

One of my friend uses both Ubuntu and windows7. Recently he switched to Windows 8 (Release Preview). But now when he boots his system he does not get option of using Ubuntu as his OS that is, he is automatically logged into windows.

Is it some minor issue which will be fixed up in the stable release of Windows 8 and so should not bother him or does he need to change some configurations in his system.

PS : I will also soon upgrade my windows 7 to 8 though I hardly use it. So I don't want to face the same issue.

Comment: Actually, no. It is a duplicate. And if it is really a bug, it is not a place to discuss that, not even bug about Ubuntu. Historically, Windows always remove Other OS's boot option, so it is happening as expected.